# Не работают горячие клавиши в Blender

Tags: blender

Единственное что работает (А может и не единственное) это NumPad и Tab все.
Использую систему Fedora linux 23.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же тема, просто у linux много горячих клавиш своих, которые конфликтуют с блендеровскими. Так, например, не работают комбинации с альтом, потому что в  линухе альт используется для многих системных команд и перненазначить его - тот еще гемор.
В блендере поковыряйся и переназначь нужные команды на другие клавиши.

Comment: То что вы написали может быть актуально для какой-то конкретной DE, но никак не для всего семейства Linux. В XFCE например ничего с альтом не конфликтует и ни для каких системных команд он не используется.

Answer (score 0):

На английскую раскладку переключись.

Answer (score 0):

Советую проверить программы автоматической смены раскладки. У меня, например, xNeur не первый раз так конфликтует с другими приложениями. Добавил Blender в список не обрабатываемых приложений и все заработало.